# as in SSIS parsing an XML with C #

Tags: c#, xml, parsing, ssis

I need to parse an XML file with the following structure, microsoft tools that I have since solved with PHP but to make the deployment in production require me to stay in C #

```html
<appointment>
    <Field name="appt_number">0</Field>
    <Field name="queue_date">0000-00-00</Field>
    <Field name="qid">000000</Field>
    <Field name="aid">00000</Field>
    <Field name="amaster_aid" />
    <Field name="type">asdasdasd</Field>
    <Field name="work_type">29</Field>
    <Field name="status">cancelled</Field>
    <Field name="appt_ext_id">0000000000000</Field>
    <Field name="eta" />
    <Field name="length">0</Field>
    <Field name="service_window_start" />
    <Field name="service_window_end" />
    <Field name="travel">0</Field>
    <Field name="zip" />
    <Field name="cust_name">ASDASD ASDASD ASDASDASD ASD ASDASD</Field>
    <Field name="address">ASDASDASDASD</Field>
    <Field name="city">ASDASDASD</Field>
    <Field name="state">ASDASDASD</Field>
    <Field name="cust_ext_id">1234567891</Field>
    <Field name="phone" />
    <Field name="device" />
    <Field name="email">ASDASDSADA@ASDASDAS.ASD</Field>
    <Field name="cell" />
    <Field name="use_phone" />
    <Field name="use_email" />
    <Field name="use_cell" />
    <Field name="language">1</Field>
    <Field name="time_zone">ASDASD</Field>
    <Field name="reminder_time">0</Field>
    <Field name="acancelled_by_external_system">1</Field>
    <Field name="time_delivered_start" />
    <Field name="time_delivered_end" />
    <Field name="sla_window_start" />
    <Field name="sla_window_end">2015-07-19 14:34:20</Field>
    <Field name="actividadPlantaExterna" />
    <Field name="procientoUtilizacionTuberia" />
    <Field name="nombreActividad">ASDASDASDA</Field>
    <Field name="areaResponsable">ASDASDASD</Field>
    <Field name="bitacoraReclamos">&lt;ASDASDASD&gt;
  &lt;ASDASDASD&gt;
    &lt;ASDASDASDASD&gt;2015-07-15 14:36:13.0&lt;/ASDASDASDASD&gt;
    &lt;ASDASDAS&gt;ASDAASDASDAS&lt;/Usuario&gt;
    &lt;ASDASDSAD&gt;ASDASDSADSAD ASDASD // ASDSADSAD-3 // ASDSADSASAASDT // ASDASDSAAS// ASDADASDAD // CASDSADADDAS // SE ASDSADADSAD//ASDSADSADSADAS // ASDSADSADASDAS &amp;#xd;
&amp;#xd;
ASDASDASD ASDASDASDA&lt;/ASDASDASDAS&gt;
    &lt;TipoBitacora&gt;ASDSADAD ASDASDAD&lt;/ASDASDSADSA&gt;
  &lt;/ASDASDSADSA&gt;
&lt;/ASDASDSADAS&gt;</Field>
    <Field name="canal117CN" />
    <Field name="canal117RF" />
    <Field name="canal2CN" />
    <Field name="canal2RF" />
    <Field name="canal38MER" />
    <Field name="canal38RF" />
    <Field name="canal46MER" />
    <Field name="canal46RF" />
    <Field name="canal67MER" />
    <Field name="canal67RF" />
    <Field name="canal92MER" />
    <Field name="canal92RF" />
    <Field name="capacidadTAP" />
    <Field name="claveDeEquipos">0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0</Field>
    <Field name="comuna">13402</Field>
    <Field name="cuadrante">-4:-18</Field>
    <Field name="customerType">RES</Field>
    <Field name="datoAdicZona" />
    <Field name="datoAdicDireccion" />
    <Field name="direccionTAP" />
    <Field name="factibFTTH">1</Field>
    <Field name="fechaAlta" />
    <Field name="fechaApertura" />
    <Field name="fechaCreacion">2015-07-15 16:04:46.0</Field>
    <Field name="idTareaPadre" />
    <Field name="internet" />
    <Field name="listadoActividades" />
    <Field name="dificultadLocalizacion" />
    <Field name="nivelesCanalesEsperados" />
    <Field name="nivelesPotenciaFTTHEsperados" />
    <Field name="noEnrutar" />
    <Field name="nodo">ALJA</Field>
    <Field name="nodoTV" />
    <Field name="numeroReclamo">ASDSADSAD</Field>
    <Field name="otrosServicios" />
    <Field name="medioFisico">ASDASD</Field>
    <Field name="estadoMedioFisico" />
    <Field name="prioridad" />
    <Field name="pruebaCorreo" />
    <Field name="rutaCobreTXT" />
    <Field name="rutaCobre" />
    <Field name="rutaFibra">&lt;ASDASDASD&gt;
  &lt;ASDASD&gt;
    &lt;ASDASD&gt;ReASDSADSADorteASD de ASDASD/ASDASDASD ASDSADAD&lt;/ASDASDASD&gt;
    &lt;ASDASDASD&gt;ASDASDADA ASDASDAS ASDASDASD ASDASDASD   ASDASDASD&lt;/ASDASDSADSAD&gt;
    &lt;ASDASDASDASDASD&gt;0&lt;/ASDASDASDSADASD&gt;
    &lt;ASDASDASDSA&gt;Zhone&lt;/ASDASDASD&gt;
    &lt;ASDASDSADSADSASA&gt;
      &lt;ASDSASA&gt;asASsASADASDA&lt;/ASDASDSADAS&gt;
</Field>
    <Field name="SIP" />
    <Field name="servicios">&lt;SDFSDF&gt;&lt;SDFSDFSDF&gt;&lt;SDFSDFSDF&gt;SDFDSFSDFSDF&lt;/SDFDSFSDFDSF&gt;&lt;SOLICITUD&gt;&lt;/SDFSDFDSF&gt;&lt;SDFDSFDS&gt;SDFSDFSDF&lt;/SDFSDFSDF&gt;&lt;SDFDSFSDFSDF&gt;SDFSDFSDFF&lt;/SDFSDFSDF&gt;&lt;/SDFSDFSDF&gt;&lt;/SDFSDFSDF&gt;</Field>
    <Field name="sinServicio" />
    <Field name="tv" />
    <Field name="ticket">54687965846</Field>
    <Field name="tipoObraCivil" />
    <Field name="tipoMantencion" />
    <Field name="tipoTuberia" />
    <Field name="trabajoSolicitado" />
    <Field name="tramasBorrar" />
    <Field name="tramas" />
    <Field name="tramosConProblemas" />
    <Field name="trunkFTTH" />
    <Field name="tecnicoTareaPadre" />
    <Field name="voz" />
    <Field name="motivoSuspencion" />
    <Field name="motivoMovimiento" />
    <Field name="motivoCambioDeEstado" />
    <Field name="motivoNoRealizado" />
    <Field name="PREGUNTA1" />
    <Field name="PREGUNTA1A" />
    <Field name="PREGUNTA1AA" />
    <Field name="PREGUNTA1B" />
    <Field name="PREGUNTA10" />
    <Field name="PREGUNTA10A" />
    <Field name="PREGUNTA11" />
    <Field name="PREGUNTA2" />
    <Field name="PREGUNTA2A" />
    <Field name="PREGUNTA2B" />
    <Field name="PREGUNTA3" />
    <Field name="PREGUNTA3A" />
    <Field name="PREGUNTA4" />
    <Field name="PREGUNTA4A" />
    <Field name="PREGUNTA5" />
    <Field name="PREGUNTA5A" />
    <Field name="PREGUNTA7" />
    <Field name="PREGUNTA7A" />
    <Field name="PREGUNTA7B" />
    <Field name="PREGUNTA8" />
    <Field name="PREGUNTA8A" />
    <Field name="PREGUNTA9" />
    <Field name="PREGUNTA9A" />
    <Field name="actividadPrincipal" />
    <Field name="activityLocationID" />
    <Field name="autorizarMover" />
    <Field name="autorizarCompletar" />
    <Field name="autorizarNoRealizar" />
    <Field name="autorizarSuspender" />
    <Field name="bitacoraTecnicos" />
    <Field name="canal117CNOUT" />
    <Field name="canal117RFOUT" />
    <Field name="canal2CNOUT" />
    <Field name="canal2RFOUT" />
    <Field name="canal38MEROUT" />
    <Field name="canal38RFOUT" />
    <Field name="canal46MEROUT" />
    <Field name="canal46RFOUT" />
    <Field name="canal67MEROUT" />
    <Field name="canal67RFOUT" />
    <Field name="canal92MEROUT" />
    <Field name="canal92RFOUT" />
    <Field name="checkListTV" />
    <Field name="checklistRealizado" />
    <Field name="comentariosDeCierre">SDFSDFSDFSDFSDFSDFDSFDSFDSDSFSDFSFS</Field>
    <Field name="duracionPrevista" />
    <Field name="fotosRegistradas" />
    <Field name="gestionManual" />
    <Field name="anteriorArmario_1310nm" />
    <Field name="anteriorCasa_1310nm" />
    <Field name="anteriorMufa_1310nm" />
    <Field name="medidaArmario_1310nm" />
    <Field name="medidaCasa_1310nm" />
    <Field name="medidaMufa_1310nm" />
    <Field name="anteriorArmario_1490nm" />
    <Field name="anteriorMufa_1490nm" />
    <Field name="anteriorCasa_1490nm" />
    <Field name="medidaArmario_1490nm" />
    <Field name="medidaCasa_1490nm" />
    <Field name="medidaMufa_1490nm" />
    <Field name="anteriorArmario_1550nm" />
    <Field name="anteriorCasa_1550nm" />
    <Field name="anteriorMufa_1550nm" />
    <Field name="medidaArmario_1550nm" />
    <Field name="medidaCasa_1550nm" />
    <Field name="medidaMufa_1550nm" />
    <Field name="ID_de_Actividad" />
    <Field name="Instancia" />
    <Field name="Solicitud" />
  </appointment>
```

I have no more idea how to do this, I need your help to find a solution, thank you very much!

Comment: What is the result you want to achieve?

Comment: el resultado puede ser un archivo nuevo xml o directamente a una tabla en la base de datos, la idea es poder automatizar una carga diaria con ese y mas archivos de similares caracteristicas, si fuese un XML seria de la siguiente forma : 

<appointment>
      <appt_number>789456</appt_number>
      <queue_date>0000-00-00</queue_date>
      ..........
</appointment>

Comment: the result may be a new xml file or directly to a table in the database, the idea is to automate a daily charge for that and more files similar characteristics, if an XML would be as follows:
<appointment>
       <appt_number> 789456 </ appt_number>
       <queue_date> 0000-00-00 </ queue_date>
       ..........
</ appointment>